# Working around 16M limit with a join-like query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

Given the architecture below, is there a way that I can query the people collection based on the searchable columns and get back an object such as this?

```
organization with people: {
    _id: "13efdsf31r23rwes"
    name: "Name",
    wp_slug: "/wordpress-slug/",
    type: "Cemetary",
    file_name: "something.csv",
    columns: [
        { label: "Maiden Name", name: "maiden_name", hidden: false },
        { label: "First Name", name: "first_name", hidden: false },
        { label: "First Pet", name: "first_pet", hidden: true },
    ],
    people: [
        { 
            _id: "13okekdsf12313", 
            "organization_id": 13efdsf31r23rwes,
            "maiden_name": "Gilomen",
            "surname": "Black", 
            "first_name": "Maria", 
            "first_pet": "Bud the Dog",
            "searchable_columns": {
                "surname": ["Black", "Gilomen"],
                "given": ["Maria"],
            }
        },
        { 
            _id: "1231sdf1313ewfd", 
            "organization_id": 13efdsf31r23rwes,
            "maiden_name": "Portland",
            "surname": "Smith", 
            "first_name": "Rose", 
            "first_pet": "Max the Dog",
            "searchable_columns": {
                "surname": ["Smith", "Portland"],
                "given": ["Rose"],
            }
        },
        ]
}
```

Current architecture:

```
organization document example: {
    _id: "13efdsf31r23rwes"
    name: "Name",
    wp_slug: "/wordpress-slug/",
    type: "Cemetary",
    file_name: "something.csv",
    columns: [
        { label: "Maiden Name", name: "maiden_name", hidden: false },
        { label: "First Name", name: "first_name", hidden: false },
        { label: "First Pet", name: "first_pet", hidden: true },
    ],
}

people collection: [
    { 
        _id: "13okekdsf12313", 
        "organization_id": 13efdsf31r23rwes,
        "maiden_name": "Gilomen",
        "surname": "Black", 
        "first_name": "Maria", 
        "first_pet": "Bud the Dog",
        "searchable_columns": {
            "surname": ["Black", "Gilomen"],
            "given": ["Maria"],
        }
    },
    { 
        _id: "1231sdf1313ewfd", 
        "organization_id": 13efdsf31r23rwes,
        "maiden_name": "Portland",
        "surname": "Smith", 
        "first_name": "Rose", 
        "first_pet": "Max the Dog",
        "searchable_columns": {
            "surname": ["Smith", "Portland"],
            "given": ["Rose"],
        }
    },
]
```

Unfortunately we have hit the 16M document limit when they are stored as a combined document, so I need to do this workaround. Is this possible to do with a straight MongoDB query, or is there no other way than to query twice? There are about 5 million records of people and 500+ organizations. Any help would be appreciated, especially if shown in MongoPHP format.

Comment: There's no way to get a document from mongodb that exceeds max document size (it's called max size for a reason). Do several queries (or request several smaller documents) and join in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround the size limitation. Using the "desired structure", I split the intended document into multiple documents of a size under 16M. Using an aggregate query, I was able to combine all of the splits back together.

```
$documents_with_results = $db->organization_data->aggregate(array(
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query),
        array( '$unwind' => '$p' ),
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query),
        array( '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$_id',
            'name' => array( '$first' => '$n' ),
            'slug' => array( '$first' => '$ws' ),
            'people' => array( '$push' => '$p' )
        ))
    ));
```